# Codeigniter 4 Routes conflict

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

```
$routes->get('MATCH ANYTHING WHICH STARTS WITH sell-', 'Home::navigator/$1');
```

I want to match any URI which starts with "sell-" without the quotes and redirect to the Home controller navigator method.

For instance, /sell-my-car should be redirected. /sell should not be redirected.

How do I accomplish it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to match a desired uri, like:

```
$routes->get('(^sell-.*)', 'Home::navigator/$1');
```

This will match everything starting with "sell-", but not "sell".

More on regex:
https://www.regular-expressions.info/